# Cannot render pdf file in contentdocument in PDFjs viewer using salesforce URLs

Tags: contentdocumentlink, getcontentaspdf

I am creating a simple PDF viewer using PDFjs library (pdfjs-4.0.379-dist), where I have viewer.html and js in static resources, and pdf.mjs and pdf.worker.mjs library from CDN in viewer. Using CDN because pdf.Worker.mjs and pdf.worker.mjs.map is greater than 5MB in size.

I have a LWC viewer with iframe which access viewer.html in static resources, where URL is passed for file.

I have used "/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/"
and have generated ContentDistrubition record and used both 'ContentDownloadUrl' and 'DistributionPublicUrl', but none of this is working.

lwc html

```html
<template>
    <template if:true={fileID}>
       <iframe src={viewerUrl} style='height: 700px; width:100%'></iframe>

    </template>
    
    <template if:false={fileID}>
        <lightning-card><div class="slds-text-align_center">No related file found.</div></lightning-card>
    </template>
</template>
```

LWC JS

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import PDFJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfjs';
import getRelatedFilesByRecordId from '@salesforce/apex/SQX_PDFViewerController.getRelatedFilesByRecordId2';

export default class sqxPDFJSViewer extends LightningElement {
    // Current record ID. *recordId* is a reserved identifier
    @api recordId;
    // Specify which file for child component to render
    @track fileID;

    @wire(getRelatedFilesByRecordId, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredFieldValue({ error, data }) {
        debugger;
        if (data) {
            this.error = undefined;           
            //const fileIDs = Object.keys(data);
            this.fileID =  data; 
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.fileID = undefined; 
        }
    }

    get viewerUrl() {
        debugger; 
        //const distributionURL = "/sfc/p/Ec000001TvVO/a/Ec0000004hJJ/MJgklqeZPrRJvQEF1Nex2MqPV9gel0oNFU4fTRNp87o";
        //const distributionDURL = "/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00DEc000001TvVO&ids=068Ec000001UnIr&d=%2Fa%2FEc0000004hJJ%2FMJgklqeZPrRJvQEF1Nex2MqPV9gel0oNFU4fTRNp87o&asPdf=false";
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=" + encodeURIComponent(distributionDURL);
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/" + this.fileID;
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=" + this.fileID; 
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=sample.pdf"
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=images/sample1.pdf"
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=../sample2.pdf"
        //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=/sfc/p/#Ec000001TvVO/a/Ec0000004hJJ/MJgklqeZPrRJvQEF1Nex2MqPV9gel0oNFU4fTRNp87o"
        return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html";
    }
}
```

Note: works fine when I use file root url uploaded in same static resources like file in different folders eg:

```javascript
 //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=sample.pdf"
 //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=images/sample1.pdf"
 //return PDFJS + "/web/viewer.html?file=../sample2.pdf"'''
```